# Nonlinear Differential Equations Find A General Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

At a complete loss for this problem, doesn't really match what we've been doing. Prof is showing rather than teaching us the subject:

Show that the solution $$y =\frac 1 {\mu(t)} \left( \int_{t_0}^t \mu(s)g(s) \, ds + c\right)$$ to the differential equation $$y\,' + p(t)y = g(t)$$ can be written in the form $$y = cy_{1}(t) + y_{2}(t)$$
where c is an arbitrary constant.

There's another 2 parts to this problem but I'm hoping that with some help with the first part I should be able to do those myself. Everything seems only partially explained or unexplained so far in this subject so I may seek help elsewhere.

Comment: You didn't finish the sentence that began with "Show that".

Comment: Whoops sorry about that, not very easy to solve an incomplete problem

Comment: What are $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$?

Comment: By the way, the differential equation $y' + p(t) y = g(t)$ is ***linear***.  Cheers!

Comment: @DavisM12 : It is still unfinished, in the same way I had in mind last time. You were going to say something like "where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are [etc.etc.]". Without that your sentence cannot be understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After we add "...where $y_1$ is the solution to the homogeneous equation $y'+p(t)=0$ and $y_2$ is a particular solution to the non-homogeneous equation," we can observe that

$$y(t) = \frac{1}{\mu(t)}\int_{t_0}^t \mu(s)g(s) \; ds + \frac{c}{\mu(t)}.$$

Can you show that $y_1 = \frac{1}{\mu(t)}$ satisfies $y'+p(t) y =0$?  If so, then the other junk can be $y_2.$